# Targeting specific data from parsed JSON objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

So basically what I am trying to do is target a specific key in a parsed JSON file in AJAX using a GET request and then try to print it to the DOM in a list using a button. But when I try to target the specific key whose data I am supposed to print it returns undefined. Here's the code that I have written:

```js
getFruitsBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET' , 'fruits.JSON' , true)

    xhr.onprogress = function(){
    console.log('Getting work done')
    }

    xhr.onload = function(){
    if(this.status==200){
  
    
    let fruitObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    console.log(fruitObj)

    


    let getFruitList = document.getElementById('fruitList')

    let str = ''

    for(key in fruitObj){
    

    console.log(fruitObj[key].name)
    str += `<li>${fruitObj[key].name}</li>`

    }

    getFruitList.innerHTML = str

    }
 
    else{
    console.log('Sorry something went wrong.')
    }


    }

    xhr.send()



    })
```

I want to print the data stored in the key "name" from the JSON file which I am targeting :

```
{"fruits"  : [{"name" : "Apple" 

},

{
"name" : "Mango"
},

{
"name" : "Orange"
},

{
"name" : "Peach"
},

{
"name"  : "Almond"
},

{
"name" : "Lemon"
}

]}
```

I will be more than thankful for a simple answer.

Comment: print to console what is returned from the xhr call

Comment: What did you see in the console when `console.log(fruitObj)` executed?

Comment: @frogcoder When I print it into the console I get an array with 6 entries in which the data of my JSON file is stored in form of object literals.

Comment: @balderman I tried printing the data to the console and it gets the data correctly in form of object literals stored in an array but when I try to target the key 'name' of those object literals it returns undefined.  I have updated the question an also added the JSON file from which I am targeting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is in the `fruitObj.fruits` attribute.  It's an array of object with attribute of `name`.  Here is the code you can use.

```
let str = '';
for (fruit of fruitObj.fruits) {
  console.log(fruit.name);
  str += `<li>${fruit.name}</li>`
}
```

You can also do it without a loop.

```
let str = fruitObj.fruits.map(fruit => `<li>${fruit.name}</li>`).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

just loop over the array

```
fruitObj.fruits.map((fruit)=>{
    console.log(fruit.name)
})
```